# Why committing package-lock.json eliminates npm SignalR installation error?

Tags: npm, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I upgraded my .Net Core 2.0 project to **2.1**. Then I tried to install **SignalR** (specifically the client library):

Inside Visual Studio 2017 package manager console, I initialized package.json (actually I do not know what does this file do):

```
PM> npm init -y
```

Then I tried to install signalR:

```
PM> npm install @aspnet/signalr
```

Then I get this error:

```
npm : npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install @aspnet/signalr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm notice crea...mmit this file.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

+ @aspnet/signalr@1.0.0
```

After that, I committed both package.json and package-lock.json files in git, and then tried to reinstall the package. Now the error has gone.

What was that error and why it is gone by committing?

Answer (score 0):

first open package.json file in your project file then 
add this <<"private": true>> after version number and try to install signalr again.